# Stumbleupon favorites in bookmarks

Tags: firefox, stumbleupon

I use StumbleUpon a lot, but with the update to Firefox 4, the bookmarks folder with all the stuff I favorited is gone. I now have to go to their site to view my old favorites.

Anyone have any idea about what might be causing this and how I can get it back?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is go into `Add-ons > Extensions > StumbleUpon: Preferences > Search & Tagging` and make sure the "Save favorites & tags to a Firefox bookmar folder" checkbox is still checked.

If it is, try clicking the "Download Favorites" button to force a full re-download.

If that doesn't fix it, you may need to build a new Firefox profile to get things back on track. I know, on my system, upgrading from Firefox 3.6 to Firefox 4 broke my existing profile so badly that the address bar wasn't updating when I clicked links.

Thankfully, you can export your bookmarks and manually copy supplemental extension data like installed Greasemonkey scripts and Stylish userstyles if that proves necessary.